# Bug In Miller-Rabin Implementation

Tags: c, primes

I am implementing [Wikipedia's Miller-Rabin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) but don't seem to be getting even vaguely apt results. 7, 11, 19, 23 etc. are reported composite. Infact, when k>12, even 5 is shown composite. I have read the maths behind Miller-Rabin but don't quite understand it very well and am relying on the algorithm blindly. Any cues on where I'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int modpow(int b, int e, int m) {
    long result = 1;

    while (e > 0) {
        if ((e & 1) == 1) {
            result = (result * b) % m;
        }
        b = (b * b) % m;
        e >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}

int isPrime(long n,int k){
        int a,s,d,r,i,x,loop;
        if(n<2)return 0;
        if(n==2||n==3)return 1;
        if(n%2==0)return 0;

        d=n-1;
        s=0;
        while(d&1==0){
                d>>=1;
                s++;
        }


        for(i=0;i<k;i++){
                loop=0;
                a=(int)(rand()*(n-1))+1;
                x=modpow(a,d,n);
                if(x==1 || x==n-1){
                        continue;

                }
                for(r=1;r<=s;r++){
                        x=modpow(x,2,n);
                        if(x==1)return 0;
                        if(x==n-1){
                                loop=1;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if(!loop)return 0;

        }
        return 1; 

}

int main(){
        int i,k;
        scanf("%d",&k);
        for(i=5;i<100;i+=2){
                printf("%d : %d\n",i,isPrime(i,k));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too bad I'm not on campus right now, otherwise I'd have Miller himself take a peek.

Comment: Are you sure you are not reading the output wrong? What exactly are you expecting the output to be & what are you getting?

Comment: I see at least one problem; I'll post an answer real quick.

Comment: @DennisMeng : That's awesome. But I guess it would've been too much to bother him with implementation bugs. :)

Comment: @another.anon.coward : I should be getting 1 for all (probably)prime numbers and 0 for composite ones.
This is what I'm getting : http://ideone.com/bYDjV

Comment: Actually no, what I thought was a bug doesn't appear to be a bug. Really confusing bit of code though.

Comment: Oh ok, as mentioned in the responses to your question the way you are using `rand` function seems to the be problem

Comment: @DennisMeng : I am not pretty sure of the math so I agree it looks more like a conglomeration of loosely translated pseudocode. Will work to fix that as time progresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the base is not coprime to the candidate, the strong Fermat check always returns "not a probable prime".

With your mistake

```
a=(int)(rand()*(n-1))+1;
```

for a prime `p`, the base is not coprime to `p` (a multiple of `p`), if and only if the result of `rand()` has the form

```
k*p + 1
```

For small primes, that is practically guaranteed to happen even with few iterations.

The base should lie between 2 ans `n/2` (choosing bases larger than `n/2` is not necessary since `a` is a witness for compositeness if and only if `n - a` is one), so you want something like

```
a = rand() % (n/2 - 2) + 2;
```

if you don't mind the modulo bias in the random number generation that favours small remainders, or

```
a = rand() /(RAND_MAX + 1.0) * (n/2 - 2) + 2;
```

if you want to distribute the bias over the entire possible range.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed that. Using the last form that you suggested. Since I'll be keeping k pretty low, it would be better to have a distributed over the entire range.

Comment: @Adarsh `a` is distributed over the entire range also in the first form. It's just the _bias_ introduced by the fact that usually the range of numbers one is interested in is not a divisor of `RAND_MAX + 1`. `rand()` has `N = RAND_MAX + 1` possible outcomes. If you want one of `m` possible numbers, you must distribute the `N` possible numbers over `m` buckets as evenly as possible. Unless `m` is a divisor of `N`, some buckets must contain one number more than other buckets. The first formula makes the buckets 0 to `RAND_MAX % m` (inclusive) be the ones with one number more, the other method

Comment: distributes the fuller buckets over the entire range in a difficult to predict manner. If `m` is small relative to `N`, the skew of the distribution can often be neglected, but if `m` is large, that means some buckets contain one number and others two, or even some 1 and others 0 if `m > N`. In the latter cases, one should take measures to eliminate the skew (for `m < N`, with `N = k*m + r`, one could only accept results of `rand()` that are smaller than `k*m` and call `rand()` again if the result was rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll need to brush up my number theory before I can apply any probability distributions here. For now, I've just got the vague idea. I can clearly see the difference it makes to use rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX) - apparently more uniform and all, but the last bit of your comment requires some revision on my part. I'll get to it soon. Thanks. :)